# Adcolony ads not working every time

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5, ads, adcolony

I googled a lot and also i sent a mail to Adcolony
        support (http://support.adcolony.com/customer/portal/emails/new), still i didn't get
        any mail from them.

```
         I got ads perfectly, but after some time onwards im not getting any ads and also
    getting error message like "**There is currently no fill for zone  zone id with slot
     0**" 
    and also **"Video ad requested but not served in zone zone id with slot 0"**  

   Please assist me, How to get ads on every button tap on ios app.
```

Comment: yes.. i also need this req.

Answer (score 4):

The message that you are seeing is normal behavior.  When a player has reached the view limits our SDK will display this message.  While we make every effort to provide fill for every request, there is no way to guarantee that every button tap will produce an ad play as there are many factors that go into determining ad availability.

Comment: Im getting some strange behaviours on playing ad on appdelegate method, it presenting ads after 2 seconds, its disappear , my view controller rotated to landscape mode and further functionality is not going, i thing this is problem with presenting ad on window

Answer (score 1):

Many years passed by, but the problem is still actual.
I tried to use AdColony for the part of users and this error falls quite often.
It means that they have a lack of advertisers and unable to fill your request.
For the banner ads fill rate is really ridiculous.
It resulted in a much smaller profit comparing to the other well-known ad networks (up to 10 times smaller in my case).
I suggest you consider other advertising networks with a better fill rate.

Comment: can you please suggest any ad networks that work fine?

Comment: It depends on the ads you want to serve. I mostly use native ads and some banners. AdMob is quite good because of the high fill rate and you can set mediation up (ability to serve ads from other advertising networks through AdMob ad units). But the drawback is that they can automatically limit your account due to unclear reasons. In this case, you got to know how to unlock your account. The second place for me takes Facebook Audiences Network. It also has a nice fill rate and native ads support, but it is actually available for a limited number of countries.

Comment: * For a limited number of countries I mean setting up ad validating your developer account. But the ads are being served around the globe.

Comment: Admob suspended my account for no reason. thats why I am switching.. FAN is also problematic

Comment: @summyiaharis if you mean Ad serving limits in AdMob - the only way to solve it is to delete all the ad units in your account. Then it will be restored within 14 days.

Comment: no they suspended the account and whats the point of deleting all ad units, when restored they will again limit the ad serving

Comment: In my case, they limited only twice )

Comment: Anyway, I suggest you to pass ad ids dynamically and not hardcode in the app. You can start doing so with the Firebase remote config. That will give you flexibility in changing the ids without users need to update the app

Comment: @summyiaharis I have limited the publication of ads for 1 year in admob, I have not solved this problem. I will try to do this. Greetings.